# BCP utility max errors ignored

Tags: bcp

How to specify max_errors allowed is 0 when using bcp to upload data? When I use `-m 0`, it will ignore all syntax errors, and continue to upload the rest of data. Here is the bcp utility [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#m)

```
bcp table1 in c:\table1.csv -c -t, -m 0 -S server1 -T
```

Change `-m 1` will stop at the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `-m 1` will stop on the first error, which is what I am looking for.